# React/ Immutable - Basic setup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutability

I'm trying to learn/ get my head around immutable so I can set it up with React/ Redux. Here's my store setup:

**store.js**

```
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
)
```

**combine reducers:**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { UIreducer } from './UI-reducer';

export default combineReducers({
  UIreducer
});
```

**example reducer:**

```
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';

const initialState = fromJS({
  test: false
});

export const UIreducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'TEST': {
      return state.set('test', true)
    }
    default: return state
  }
}
```

I'm fairly sure i've set the above two parts up correctly, the only thing that i'm not sure about is how to map the state to props in my component:

Here's how I normally do it:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  UI: state.UIreducer
})
```

When using immutable it returns an object that immutable generates which doesn't look like a normal state object if I were to not use immutable. I tried after a bit of research to use .get with the state like so:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  UI: state.get('UIreducer')
})
```

This however returned the error message:

> state.get is not a function

Could someone please point out where i've gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember the state is the combination of all reducers, so the state will look like the combined reducers object

```
export default combineReducers({
  UIreducer
});
```

At `mapStateToProps` you should ask for `state.UIreducer` and at the component level `UI.get('test')`

Answering further questions:

1. where exactly would I write the `UI.get('test')`?

Anywhere in your component UI will be a prop for it, you can use it like this

```
const myComponent = (props) => {
 return <div>props.UI.get('test')</div>
}
```

2. I would have thought the `.get('test')` would go in the mapStateToProps somehwere.

That depends of which properties of your state you want to pass/map to your component, you can also pass an specifict

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  test: state.UIreducer.get('test')
})
```

and inside of you component

```
const myComponent = (props) => {
 return <div>props.test</div>
}
```

Comment: where exactly would I write the UI.get('test')? I would have thought the .get('test') would go in the mapStateToProps somehwere...

Comment: Edited my original answer for these questions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use redux-immutable and convert the initialState to an immutable object:

```
import {
  combineReducers
 } from 'redux-immutable';

import {
 createStore
} from 'redux';

const initialState = Immutable.Map();
const rootReducer = combineReducers({UIreducer});
```

Comment: Sorry but could you please clarify your answer a bit?